# How to install PHP PhantomJS require packages

Tags: php, phpunit, phantomjs, composer-php

I'm trying to use [PHP PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) but it's require some package to run ..
I'm composer in php and when I'm trying to install dependencies on root PHP PhantomJS

```
composer install
```

says

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

I'm confused ... anybody can help how install package that's need to run PHP PhantomJS script?

Comment: What did you do before `composer install`, i.e. what does your composer.json file look like?

Comment: dont edit .json file it's orginal that i download

Comment: I don't know all composer.json files of the world - care to give me a link to whatever you were downloading, or should I google it and hope that what I see is what you saw?

Comment: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/blob/master/composer.json it's .json file

Comment: And now we are back to step 1: What did you do before `composer install`? If you cloned that repository, or simply grabbed that composer.json as a download, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: im dont edit any thing . and just download that package .what i do now :( 

can you explane me that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you downloaded it, you have everything you need without using Composer. Composer is for downloading this and other packages, but this is not the only way of getting packages. :)

Now the easiest way to use that package is to have a new clean empty directory and execute this line:

```
composer require jonnyw/php-phantomjs:2.*
```

Now magic happens, including the creation of a composer.json file, download of that package, creation of autoloading files, and then you are done.

With an otherwise empty directory you couldn't do very much, so in order to make use of that package (or others) inside your own code, go to the root directory of your code, and execute above line. The same things happen, and then you are pretty much done - apart from the fact that you need to include the autoloader file in your own code if you want to use that package.

Comment: this line creat some empty folders and cmd say's :   [InvalidArgumentException]
  The requirement install must contain a version constraint

Comment: if it dont need any thing to run script whay show this error when run it : Fatal error: Class 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\read\test\src\a.php on line 4

Answer (score 6):

**Install PhantomJS via Composer**

Use the package ["jakoch/phantomjs-installer"](https://github.com/jakoch/phantomjs-installer).

It installs the PhantomJS binary for Linux, Windows or Mac into the `/bin` folder of your project.

1. Simply add the following lines to your projects `composer.json` file:

   ```
    {
        "require": {
            "jakoch/phantomjs-installer": "3.0.0"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "bin-dir": "bin"
        }
    }
   ```

   The version number determines which version of PhantomJS is fetched.
2. Execute `composer update` or `composer install`

Comment: FYI if you get a 404 error have a look on the currently availably PhantomJS version here https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/